# how to arrange an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If someone could look at my code it would be very helpful because I'm very new to JS and HTML.

I am trying to order the array in alphabetical order, I have looked at other threads answering this and my code doesn't seem to fit any of them. So if somone could help me order the code I would be grateful...

```js
var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Phone", "Xbox", "Laptop"];
document.getElementById("Mylist").innerHTML = products;

function myFunction() {
  products.sort();
  document.getElementById("Mylist").innerHTML = products;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="list">Click to Arrange</button>

<p id="Mylist"></p>
```

Comment: Can you state your actual question?

Comment: The first thing that pops out is `onclick="list"` – you don't have anything called "list". Did you mean `onclick="myFunction()"`?

Comment: As you can see now I created a snippet for you, you need to call `myFunction()` and not `list`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the "myFunction()"

```js
var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "phone", "Xbox", "Laptop"];
document.getElementById("Mylist").innerHTML = products;

function myFunction() {
  products = products.sort();
  document.getElementById("Mylist").innerHTML = products;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to Arrange</button>

<p id="Mylist"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your named Function `myFunction()` inside your HTML button attribute `onclick` as shown bellow

```js
var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "phone", "Xbox", "Laptop"];
document.getElementById("Mylist").innerHTML = products;

function myFunction() {
  products.sort();
  document.getElementById("Mylist").innerHTML = products;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to Arrange</button>

<p id="Mylist"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to first show the list and then sort and show again.

You need to call `myFunction()` instead of `list`

```js
var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "phone", "Xbox", "Laptop"];

window.onload=function() { // now the elements exists on the page
  document.getElementById("Mylist").innerHTML = products;
}

function myFunction() {
  products.sort();
  document.getElementById("Mylist").innerHTML = products;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to Arrange</button>

<p id="Mylist"></p>
```